# Error when installing MySQL plugin in windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to install **keyring** plugin on MySQL 5.7.21.

I edited my.cnf file.

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.dll
```

I have ran the following command to install the plugin.

```
mysql> install plugin keyring_file soname 'keyring_file.dll';
```

When i ran that command its give error.

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000):
```

Did I miss a step somewhere?

Thanx...